# Ruby on Rails API - Controller does not render the objects like they are saved in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, api, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails API, where I want the users to be able to post Strava activities. The create action in my controller should get an activity id and then load data from the Strava API and save it to the model, which is then saved:

Here is my code:

```
def create
    # Get Activity from Strava
    activity = getStravaData(params[:access_token], "activity", params[:activity_id])
    # Build Model
    run = Run.new(run_params.merge(:name => activity["name"], :distance => activity["distance"], :elapsed_time => activity["elapsed_time"]))

    # If Run is saved
    if run.save
        render json: run, status: :created, location: v1_run_url(run)
    else
        render json: run.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

The return value of the controller is correct:

```
{
    "id": 64,
    "name": "Abendlauf",
    "distance": 20980.8,
    "elapsed_time": 8318,
    ...
}
```

However, the values name, distance and elapsed_time, which are taken from the Strava API are not in the database. When I call the get-method of the Controller:

```
def show
   render json: @run
end

private
   def set_run
      @run = Run.find(params[:id])
   end
   def run_params
      params.require(:run).permit(:name, :distance, :elapsed_time, ...)
   end
```

The result looks like this:

```
{
   "id": 64,
   "name": null,
   "distance": null,
   "elapsed_time": null,
   ...
}
```

Other variation behaved exactly the same, like using attr_accessors and setting the values in the create action like this:

```
run.name = activity["name"]
run.save
```

I am lost here, I tried every method I know/I could find. Am I too stupid to see what's wrong here?^^
So, it would made my day if you can help me sorting this out. :)

Comment: Are you trying to create a run in your database from the values fetched from Strava or from values posted as params? Or are you trying to do some combination of the two?

Comment: I want the user to post just an activity-id in the params. The rest of the data will be loaded from Strava within the API. But the are somehow not persisted in the database, even tought they are rendered correctly from the create action

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating the run based on data fetched from Strava, not from POST params, there's no need to mess with `run_params`.

```
run = Run.new(:name => activity["name"], 
              :distance => activity["distance"],
              :elapsed_time => activity["elapsed_time"])
```

This assumes you have a migration along the lines of:

```
class CreateRun < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :runs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :distance
      t.integer :elapsed_time
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good point, thank you. But the issue was in the model (sorry for not posting that). These lines prevented the data to be saved: ``validates :distance, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }
validates :elapsed_time, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }``

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case you should have received an error 422: `unprocessable_entity`.

Comment: Yeah, right. But I didn't^^ It just didn't care about the values and saved it as null